# How to add text and arrows nicely to lengthy equations?

Tags: equations, arrows, split

This is a screenshot from one of the papers of the Dozenal Society:

[image]

I'd like to ask, how you can do those arrows in LaTeX as they did in their equations.

A couple other things: Are those three math environments in a minipage that has been split into three?

And I'm guessing the way to do the justification is an `align*` environment with the `&` in the appropriate locations?

Primary questions are those arrows though. I never used them, but I'd sure like to know how to do those like that.

Comment: Should be pretty easy with tikzmark plus normal t kz. Search the site for tikzmark examples

Comment: Easy also with `pst-node` , from the `pstricks` family.